# Get envelopeID from a string using regex

Tags: java, regex

I have following strings :

```
"envelopeId": "fsadjhfkhdsgf", "ashgjkadsagagsalkjghsag": "gsajgks", "envelopeId": "fsadjhfkhdsgfgsd", "afshdj":"gas"
```

And I need to extract out all `envelopeIds` from this. I have tried different `regex` but nothing seems to work.

`(?:"envelopeId": ")*(",)`

`(?:"envelopeId": ")*[\d\D](",)`

What is wrong with the `regex` I am trying?

Comment: Use `"\"envelopeId\":\\s*\"([^\"]+)\""` string literal as pattern. grab `matcher.group(1)`

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: Yes. It did. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
"envelopeId":\s*"([^"]+)"
```

And extract `matcher.group(1)` values. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/j7V4B2/1).

**Details**

- `"envelopeId":` - a literal string
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `"` - a `"` char
- `([^"]+)` - Group 1: any 1+ chars other than `"`
- `"` - a `"` char.

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/yXLga8):

```
String s = "\"envelopeId\": \"fsadjhfkhdsgf\", \"ashgjkadsagagsalkjghsag\": \"gsajgks\", \"envelopeId\": \"fsadjhfkhdsgfgsd\", \"afshdj\":\"gas\"";
String key = "envelopeId";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"" + Pattern.quote(key) + "\":\\s*\"([^\"]+)\"");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); 
}
```

Output:

```
fsadjhfkhdsgf
fsadjhfkhdsgfgsd
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code to extract `envelopeId`s from line string. Anyway this is not recommended to extract json text values from json text. Instead of that use json library to parse the text and extract values by keys.

```
String line = "\"envelopeId\": \"fsadjhfkhdsgf\", \"ashgjkadsagagsalkjghsag\": \"gsajgks\", \"envelopeId\": \"fsadjhfkhdsgfgsd\", \"afshdj\":\"gas\"";
String pattern = "(?<=\"envelopeId\"\\: \")\\w+";

Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

Matcher m = r.matcher(line);

while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```